# Java: Is "9" appearing in my run an Eclipse bug?

Tags: java, eclipse

While writing my code for a computer dating assignment in which we see the compatibility of an array of four objects, my code printed strangely. (Eclipse didn't give me an error/warning at first).

Code:

```
System.out.print("Fit between " + profile1.getTitle() + " and " + profile2.getTitle() + ": \n   " +
       + '\t' + profile1.fitValue(profile2) + '\n');
```

When I tried to print things out, they appeared like this:

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Elizabeth Bennett: 
   90.0

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Fitzwilliam Darcy: 
   90.55

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Romeo Montague: 
   90.3

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Juliet Capulet: 
   90.0

.......................................................so on so forth.

There was a "9" appearing in front of my numbers.

I found the problem later: I had two concatenating operators ("+") after my "\n". So I changed my code, deleting the extraneous "+".

New code:

```
System.out.print("Fit between " + profile1.getTitle() + " and " + profile2.getTitle() + ": \n   " +
       '\t' + profile1.fitValue(profile2) + '\n');
```

New correct run:

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Elizabeth Bennett: 
    0.0

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Fitzwilliam Darcy: 
    0.55

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Romeo Montague: 
    0.3

Fit between Elizabeth Bennett and Juliet Capulet: 
    0.0

..............................................so on so forth.

Though I've thankfully found my problem, I want to know what exactly is causing this to happen. Is there some sort of eclipse shorthand that leads to the "9"'s appearance? Or is this due to some eclipse bug? I'm still a beginner at java, so I can't make a solid conclusion.

I tried modifying my code slightly to see how Eclipse would react (I deleted the space between my original "+ +"):

```
System.out.print("Fit between " + profile1.getTitle() + " and " + profile2.getTitle() + ": \n   " ++
       '\t' + profile1.fitValue(profile2) + '\n');
```

Eclipse gave me this warning:

Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error on token "++", + 
   expected
- Invalid argument to operation ++/--

This makes sense, because ++ on its own is an operator of sorts. 
Interestingly, however, if I put a space between the "++", then the warning disappears.

I didn't paste my entire code for the sake of readability, but if necessary, I can edit and add it in.
Some clarification regarding this would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not just with the `+ +` in your code. But it's also with the fact that you are using **char** `'\t'` and not **String** `"\t"`.

So when you use `System.out.println("Hello" + '\t');`, the `\t` is taken as a character literal and appended to the string as `\t`.

But when you use `System.out.println("Hello" + + '\t');`, it becomes effectively `System.out.println("Hello" + (+ '\t'));`. So it is treated as an `int` by java. You only assign `+` and `-` signs to ints, not chars.

Remember you can do `int i = +2` or `-2` or `+ +2`.

And the ASCII value of `\t` is `9`. Hence it gets appended to the string and get's printed as `Hello9`.

Comment: Where are you getting the extra `\n` there?

Comment: @Jon corrected it. If `\n` was there, the `9` would be printed in a new line.

Comment: @jWeaver, You have misunderstood. `\n` was not present instead of `\t`. Check my edit, you will understand.

Comment: @Codebender I see. I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not a bug. It's unusual, but it's not a bug.

The first thing to do is simplify the example massively:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String start = "Start";
        String end = "End";
        System.out.println(start + '\t' + end);
        System.out.println(start + +'\t' + end);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Start   End
Start9End
```

Now admittedly I'm using strings for both `start` and `end`, but due to `+` being left-associative, that doesn't make any difference here. (If `start` were an integer, the first binary `+` operator would be integer addition in both cases.)

Basically, the extra `+` ends up being a [unary `+` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3) with `'\t'` as the operand. [Unary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) is applied to the `char`, giving `int` as a result. So the code becomes effectively:

```
System.out.println(start + +((int)'\t') + end);
```

which is effectively:

```
System.out.println(start + +(9) + end);
```

which is effectively

```
System.out.println(start + 9 + end);
```

... at which point it's hopefully clear why you're getting the output you are.

To avoid accidentally ending up treating a character as an integer, it's probably best to just use strings instead - at which point the code *won't* compile because there's no unary `+` operator for `String`:

```
System.out.println(start + +"\t" + end);
```

... gives:

```
Test.java:6: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '+'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `char` `\t` and not the string `"\t"` with the `+` operator so it is using the [ascii numeric value of 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) for tab

so

```
System.out.println("\n"+ +'\t');
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println("\n"+ (+9));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with eclipse. It works the same way on console also. The +'\t' is considered as integer value 9 by Java not as a Character.